# Can't get the Typed value of HTML5 Number Inputs in Javascript

Tags: javascript, function, html-input

I want to create a Retirement Calculator. I am stuck on getting the value that someone types for their current age and the age they want to retire at, so I can subtract the retiring age by the current age to get the number of years to calculate. I want to get the value's typed after I submit the button and I want it to show up as an alert or console.log() it just to know it works. Right now it is showing [object MouseEvent] instead of the number I want to show up. Any help would be greatly appreciated. I'm not that good at JavaScript yet but need to figure this out for a site.

I've tried .value and .innerHTML. I've tried Name functions, and anonymous functions, local and global variables, etc.

```
$(function () {
   $(".number-input").keydown(function (e) {
       if ((e.keyCode == 65 && (e.ctrlKey === true || e.metaKey === true)) ||
         (e.keyCode >= 35 && e.keyCode <= 40) ||
         $.inArray(e.keyCode, [46, 8, 9, 27, 13, 110, 190]) !== -1) {
         return;
      }
      if ((e.shiftKey || (e.keyCode < 48 || e.keyCode > 57)) &&
         (e.keyCode < 96 || e.keyCode > 105)) {
          e.preventDefault();
      }
   });
});
  // Variables
var currentAge = document.getElementById('age-current');

var retireAge = document.getElementById('age-retire');

var monthlyInvestment = document.getElementById('monthly-investment');

var annualReturn = document.getElementById('annual-return');

  // Limit # of Characters Functions
currentAge.oninput = function () {
  if(this.value.length > 2) {
    this.value = this.value.slice(0,2);
  }
}

retireAge.oninput = function() {
  if(this.value.length > 2){
    this.value = this.value.slice(0,2);
  }
}

monthlyInvestment.oninput = function (){
  if(this.value.length > 6){
    this.value = this.value.slice(0,6);
  }
}

annualReturn.oninput = function () {
  if(this.value.length > 6) {
    this.value = this.value.slice(0,6);
  }
}

  // Allow a percentage input
$(document).on('keydown', 'input[pattern]', function(e){
  var input = $(this);
  var oldVal = input.val();
  var regex = new RegExp(input.attr('pattern'), 'g');

  setTimeout(function(){
    var newVal = input.val();
    if(!regex.test(newVal)){
      input.val(oldVal); 
    }
  }, 0);
});

  // JS math to calculate return

// Example Funcgtion futureValue = investment*Math.pow((1+annualRate), 
years);


//Age Value Functions

 var currentAge = currentAge.value;
 var retireAge = retireAge.value;



// Button Submit

function getYears (retireAge, currentAge) {
 years = retireAge - currentAge;
  return years;
}

var btnSubmit = document.getElementById('submit');

btnSubmit.onclick = function (years){
  alert(years);
}
```

I want to be able to take the value of both ages (currentAge - retireAge) and have the values stored in var years. Then show in an alert or console.log() when I click the submit button to know that it's working.

Comment: can you provide a jsfiddle so that we can reproduce the outputs?

Comment: Two things to start you off. First, you should use the `HTMLInputElement` attributes to control the values. Set the `type` attribute to `number` and set the `min` and `max` attributes for the age ranges. Then you can get rid of 4 functions. Next, you must realize that everything that comes from the browser is a String (text). So you to perform mathematics on those `.value`s, you must use `parseInt()` or `parseFloat()` to convert them into number you can do math with. Yes, you get the value of the `input` element using the `.value` property.